# Poor audio quality with getUserMedia. Any ideas why?

Tags: javascript, audio-recording, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to set up an audio recorder in a React web application for recording large groups of people (15+) talking, but can't seem to get the recording quality right. I initially tried capturing the audio recordings by passing the following constraints to getUserMedia:

```
const constraints = {
  audio: {
    sampleRate: 48000,
    channelCount: 1,
    volume: 1.0,
    echoCancellation: true,
    noiseSuppression: true,
  },
  video: false
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then( stream => {
  this.processStream(stream);
})

processStream = stream => {
  let options = MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('audio/webm') ? {
    mimeType: 'audio/webm'
  } : {};

  let recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

  ...

}
```

For most recordings, the recording quality was good. Sometimes, however, the recording would end up with the this really bad, distorted, almost metallic-sounding quality. I haven't been able to figure out how to reproduce the effect (I have since started capturing the users' browser, to try to help debug this problem).

About a week ago, I deployed the app with constraints = { audio: true, video: false }, but this too sometimes produces recordings with slightly distorted qualities. So far, none of the recordings have been as bad as some of the recordings before, but the quality is still not where we want it to be.

Today, I set the constraints to:

```
const constraints = {
    audio: {
      echoCancellation: false,
      autoGainControl: false,
      noiseCancellation: false
    },
    video: false
}
```

But I'm doubtful that this will be the magic ticket to high quality recordings, and I'm starting to think that maybe I should ditch MediaRecorder for something else. Does anyone have ideas about 1) what the problem is and 2) how we might fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Just in case anyone sees this last snippet, it's very useful to quicky disable browser's audio processing, but **noiseCancellation is wrong**, it should say `noiseSuppression: false`

Answer (score 6):

You should never set the `sampleRate` value in the `getUserMedia` constraints! The `sampleRate` is set **by the client** automatically and modifying it would result in gaping sounds. The value you set, `48000`, for example, is compatible only with Google Chrome. Firefox and Edge use totally different values.

Also, when you set `echoCancellation` and `noiseSuppression` to `true`, this means the microphone will mute itself when the gain is close to `0`. This will result in broken speech when the person starts to talk and ends his sentences.

From my own experience, you should just set the constrains to `audio` alone, and let the browser do the rest:

```
const constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: false
}
```

Comment: "You should never set the sampleRate value in the getUserMedia constraints".  Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I can't find, and don't know of, anything that supports always avoiding setting the `sampleRate`. However, unless there is a specific reason you need all the audio samples, across clients, in the same sample rate, I'd just take the client defaults. Even if you implement constraints, because you need them to be the same sample rate, it won't guarantee they are all the same rate. You'd still want to process the audio server side to guarrantee they are the same.

Comment: You can manipulate the sampleRate value, but only based on information about supported audio devices. In my experience with windows applications, setting a const (miss) value resulted in bad quality or a bug.

Answer (score 3):

The offender is noiseSuppression: true
This should be set to **false**

Comment: Same for me. Disabling noise suppression improved the recording quality dramatically. I had to disable it explicitly with `audio: { noiseSuppression: false }` because the browser insisted on turning it on by default when I used the constraint `audio: true`.

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues both in Firefox and Chrome, due to `noiseSuppression` and `echoCancellation` respectively, setting them to false fixed it

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: {
    deviceId,
    noiseSuppression: false,
    echoCancellation: false,
  },
});
```

Comment: This fixed my issue! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

Use the Adapter.js library from google